# Unable to access js property

Tags: javascript, json

I've json in this format :

```
[
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "560c079e1691682b4ff327ad"
        },
        "year": "2015",
        "month": "9",
        "day": "30",
        "time": "17:02:17",
        "problemDesc": "test",
        "resolution": "test",
        "IM": "test"
    }
]
```

I'm attempting to access the year using : `console.log(json[0].year)` but receiving `undefined`. How to access the year value from this json string ?

fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/b8dggkof/

Comment: You have a string and it is not valid JSON in that string either - here is one that works http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/pkzuf8b7/

Comment: are there any extra characters? I am getting an error when trying to access your json object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the JSFiddle the value inside `json` is a string and not a JavaScript Object, you have to parse the string before try to access the value:

```js
var json = JSON.parse('{"":[{"_id":{"$oid":"560c079e1691682b4ff327ad"},"year":"2015","month":"9","day":"30","time":"17:02:17","problemDesc":"test","resolution":"test","IM":"test"}]}');

console.log(json[''][0].year);
```

After you parsed the string, you need to access the object with key an empty string:

```
json['']
```

The value associated to this key is an array and you need the first element, so:

```
json[''][0]
```

Now you can get the year:

```
json[''][0].year
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put in a key for the JSON and then access by the key the inner Object, after you parse it since it is a string enclosed in quotes '

```
var json = '{"key":[{"_id":{"$oid":"560c079e1691682b4ff327ad"},"year":"2015","month":"9","day":"30","time":"17:02:17","problemDesc":"test","resolution":"test","IM":"test"}]}'

console.log(JSON.parse(json)['key'][0].year);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to parse you `json string` to `json object` by using `JSON.parse` then use `key name` in you case which is `''(empty string)`

```js
var jsonStr = '{"":[{"_id":{"$oid":"560c079e1691682b4ff327ad"},"year":"2015","month":"9","day":"30","time":"17:02:17","problemDesc":"test","resolution":"test","IM":"test"}]}';
var parseJson = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
alert(parseJson[''][0].year)
```